# Formula for integration bounds of recursively defined polynomial sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

We can recursively define a sequence of polynomials by

$$P_0(x) := 1$$

and then with the definite integral

$$P_n(x) := \int_{c_n}^x P_{n-1}(t) ~\mathrm dt$$

where the $c_n$ are to be chosen so that

$$\int_0^1 P_n(t)~\mathrm dt = 0$$

so for $n = 1$ we have $P_1(x) = x - c_1$ so $c_1 = 1/2$. However already for $n=2$ it becomes difficult since $\int_{c_2}^x (t-1/2)~\mathrm dt =  t^2/2 - t/2- c_2^2/2 + c_2/2$ and to have $\int_0^1 P_2(t)~\mathrm dt = 0$ there are two solutions for $c_2$ namely

$$c_2 = 1/2 \pm \sqrt 3/6.$$

So $P_2(x) = x^2/2 - x/2 + 1/12$. For $n=3$ we get $c_3 = 0$ and $P_3(x) = x^3/6 - x^2/4 + x/12$ however for $n=4$ we have $c_4=1/2 - 1/2\sqrt (1 - 2/15\sqrt 30)$ (and 3 other solutions) for $P_4(x)=x^4/24 - x^3/12 + x^2/24 - 1/720$. For $n=5$ again $c_5=0$ (however there are another 4 solutions). Is there some general Formula for the $c_n$ so we could have a shortcut for calculating the coefficients of $P_n(x)$? Also with an eye to fractional calculus it would be nice to know if for the Riemann-Liouville integral

$$\frac1{\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_c^x P(t) (x-t)^{\alpha-1}~\mathrm dt$$
and

$$\int_0^1 P(t)~\mathrm dt = 0$$

if there even is a solution for this - let alone if it would fit in the previously defined sequence. The dream result would of course be not only to have a formula for $c_n$ but a function $c(n)$ that continuously defines such a polynomial sequence. But that seems very remote since even in simple cases with for example $\alpha = 1/2$ and $c>0$ the integral produces complex values...

Comment: Are you really interested in the $c$'s or do you simply want to have the polynomials $P_n(t)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't comment, but your problem looks awfully like the method for generating the Bernoulli polynomials $B_n(x)$, except that instead of the relation $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}P_n(x)=P_{n-1}(x)$ that you have, the Bernoulli polynomials have the relation $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}B_n(x)=nB_{n-1}(x)$. That might be something to start with...

---

As Fabian seems to have settled the relationship of your polynomials to the more conventional Bernoulli polynomials, I'll address the question of generalizing the Bernoulli polynomials to arbitrary index; one way to this is the use of the exponential generating function

$$\frac{t\exp(zt)}{\exp(t)-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n(z)}{n!}t^n$$

along with the Cauchy differentiation formula

$$f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\mathrm dz;$$

i.e., consider the contour integral

$$B_\alpha(z)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{t\exp(zt)}{\exp(t)-1} \frac{\mathrm dt}{t^{\alpha+1}},$$

where $\gamma$ is an anticlockwise contour that doesn't cross the negative real axis, and is within the circle with radius $2\pi$ (due to the restricted radius of convergence of the EGF). I'd say more, but it seems there is [prior work by Butzer *et al.*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0893-9659%2892%2990020-A), and thus I'll just have to ask you to see that paper.

Comment: @Peter: [This](http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/2223/2223A.pdf) and [this](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/scw21/papers/97051/97051.ps.gz) may be of interest as well.

Comment: I don't seem to recall linking to Wikipedia anywhere in my answer, @Peter... :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't know about the $c$'s. But finding the polynomials $P_n(t)$ is not so hard. As gorilla already noted
$$\frac{d}{dx} P_n(t) = P_{n-1}(t). \qquad  (1)$$
This determines the polynomials $P_n(t)$ 
together with the normalization
$$\int_0^1 dt\, P_n(t) = 0 \qquad n\neq0 \qquad (2)$$
and the initial condition $P_0(t)=1$ uniquely (all the different $c$'s in you post which are the solutions of some polynomial equation lead to the *same*  $P_n$!).

Every recursion step adds a degree to the polynomial and therefore we can parameterize the $n$-th polynomial as
$$ P_n(t) = \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{a_{n-j}}{j!} t^j = \frac{a_0}{n!} t^n + \frac{a_1}{(n-1)!} t^{n-1}+ \dots\;.$$
With this ansatz Eq. (1) is automatically fulfilled. Equation (2) leads to the condition
$$ \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{a_{n-j}}{(j+1)!} =0$$
with the solution
$$a_n = -\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{a_{n-j}}{(j+1)!}.$$
This defines a recursion relation for the coefficients $a_n$ (with $a_0=1$ as initial condition).

The recursion relation has the solution
$a_n = \frac{B_n}{n!}$
with $B_n$ the $n$-th [Bernoulli number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). The polynomial $P_n$ thus are given by
$$P_n(t) = \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{B_{n-j}}{j!(n-j)!} t^j = \frac{B_n(t)}{n!},$$
with $B_n(t)$ the [Bernoulli polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials).